# Why do lines and rects not match up in Fabricjs

Tags: fabricjs

Why does the following rect and lines not match up?
[image: off-center rect]

The lines are 1px apart, 5px long, starting from (0,0)

The rect is `top: 0, left: 0, width: 1, height: 1`

[Running fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5KKQ2/6194/)

Am I missing something with lines?

Comment: why you are zooming the canvas `canvas.setZoom(50);`? is there any requirement? check [grid](http://jsfiddle.net/fabricjs/S9sLu/) example.

Comment: @Durga I've had discrepancies with how fonts are rendered, I've narrowed it down this issue. I'm zooming in to show the issue, we won't see half a pixel at 0 zoom.

Comment: Its because `strokeWidth` of rect object, make it zero, it will work as expected. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x8o19yLj/)

Comment: @Durga That did it! Please make an answer so I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The padding you got because of `strokeWidth` of the `Rect` object, make it zero, it will work as expected. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x8o19yLj/)

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var gridLine = function(at, stroke, canvas, length) {
  var horizontal = [0, at, length, at];
  var vertical = [at, 0, at, length];

  let hLine = new fabric.Line(horizontal, {
    strokeWidth: 0.02,
    stroke,
  });
  let vLine = new fabric.Line(vertical, {
    strokeWidth: 0.02,
    stroke,
  });
  canvas.add(hLine);
  canvas.add(vLine);
}

var showGrid = function(fabric) {
  var count = 5;
  var separationPx = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    gridLine(i * separationPx, "silver", fabric, count);
  }
}

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  width: 1,
  height: 1,
  fill: "red",
  strokeWidth: 0
});

showGrid(canvas);
canvas.add(rect);

canvas.setZoom(50);
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.3.4/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner to Fabricjs so there might be an easier answer. To me it looks like the "padding" (?) is what causes the problem. Look at the control borders when you select the rectangle, they do align but are bigger than your rectangle is.

I could fix this by setting the rect to (-0.5, -0.5, 1, 1), however I think this is not the best workaround and you should probably try to adjust the padding of your rect.

Hope it helps in a way.

Cheers!

**Edit:** It's not the padding it's the strokeWidth as Durga pointed out in the comments to the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem:

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/odwg3nsq/]
```

[image]

You could set the padding/margin of the outer container, but in the canvas everything is ok with the rectangle.

Comment: I think I'm missing something with your answer. What does your image illustrate?
There is a problem, there's a half a pixel difference between the origin for the lines and the origin for the square.